# Editing preview content of an already shared link on Facebook

Tags: facebook

Let's say that I've shared a link on Facebook, simply by pasting a link, and letting it be scraped. After the scraping is done, I deleted the link from the input box, and clicked on publish.

Now, say that I've noticed that there's something wrong with the text in the preview box - spelling, unnecessary information, etc. Is it possible to edit it in some way? I know that I can edit the content prior to publishing, but what are my options after posting? Short of deleting the entire post, and posting it again, I mean.

Facebook offers [this](https://www.facebook.com/help/462476073850410?helpref=uf_permalink), but it doesn't help, seeing how my post has no content, other than the linked page.